# Python map two list based on condition true

Tags: list, python-2.7

I have two lists:

```
A: [ True  True  True False  True False  True ]
B: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
```

I want to get only those values from list `B` where list `A` is `True`.

Desired output:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'G']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.compress(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress):

```
import itertools
a = [ True, True, True, False, True, False, True ]
b = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']

ab = itertools.compress(b, a)
print(list(ba))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to import `itertools`, simple list comprehension with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) built-in function would be enough.

```
conditions =  [True, True, True, False, True, False, True]
objects = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
result = [o for o, c in zip(objects, conditions) if c]
assert result == ['A', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'G']
```

Answer (score 0):

Fairly simple problem to be posted as a question; here is the solution. Would appreciate if you could try it before asking here.

Code:

```
a = [True, True, True, False, True, False, True]
b = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
res = []
for x in range(len(a)):
    if a[x]==True:
        res.append(b[x])
print res
```

Output:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'G']
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works for python 2 as well; I have only 3 on this PC, but still:

```
a = [ True, True, True, False, True, False, True ]
b = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
ab = []

for i, j in enumerate(a):
    if j == True:
        ab.append(b[i])
# in python 3 this was print(ab) :) I ported :)
print ab
```